# Get all updates from a Windows computer with programming

Tags: c#, powershell, wmi

I am looking for a way to get all updates from a workstation or server (Microsoft Windows).

When I look at *Control Panel → Programs → Programs and Features → Installed Updates* I can also see updates for Visual Studio and other products.

Example:

```
Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 (KB3022398)
Update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 (KB3165756)
```

But all the programmatic ways I have tried never gets me the updates for Visual Studio. How can I accomplish that?

I have tried:

```bsh
$Session = New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.Session
$Searcher = $Session.CreateUpdateSearcher()
$HistoryCount = $Searcher.GetTotalHistoryCount()
$Updates = $Searcher.QueryHistory(0,$HistoryCount)
$Updates | Select Title, @{l='Name';e={$($_.Categories).Name}}, Date | ft
```

```bsh
Get-HotFix
```

```bsh
Get-WmiObject -Class "Win32_QuickfixEngineering"
```

Any help on how to get *all* updates out in a programmatic way would be much appreciated.

Comment: Seems not related to C#? Or C# solution also will do, not just powershell one?

Comment: Any .NET (C#), Powershell, WMI or CMD line way will do for me :)

Comment: There's already a Microsoft tool for managing updates called WSUS and it can even do reporting.

Comment: Hi Bill, I know about WSUS, but I am looking for some simple code that can run on almost any Windows OS whether it is under WSUS or not.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using C#, you can do that using `WUApiLib`

```
Type t = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Microsoft.Update.Session", 
UpdateSession UpdateSession = (UpdateSession)Activator.CreateInstance(
IUpdateSearcher UpdateSearchResult = UpdateSession.CreateUpdateSearcher();
UpdateSearchResult.Online = true;
ISearchResult SearchResults = UpdateSearchResult.Search("IsInstalled=1 AND IsPresent=1");
```

Second option is to read information from below mentioned registry key

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
```